# how to authenticate 3rd api along with nextauth's JWT session

Tags: next.js, jwt, next-auth

I have two components:

- `mydomain` runs a nextjs along with next-auth.js
- `api.mydomain` runs a back-end API that `mydomain`'s client points to make some request

`Mydomain` is authenticated via the Next.js's Github provider, and as long as I get next-auth.js creates a JWT session which is sent to the client as a form of a cookie (correct me if I'm wrong). Then, if you need some info about your authentication, you can use the hook `useSession` on front side in order to access your JWT session.

My frontend is not using the `api` nextjs' functionality though: it communicates with an API through axios HTTP calls, which is deployed separately. What I would like to do is passing the Nextjs' JWT to my backend in order to verify authentication and authorization, but I'm not sure if it's possible, safe and recommended.

So: how could I accomplish that? The only alternative I see is generating a separated JWT token within the JWT callback, pass back to the front and use it for my calls, but I see it like a redundant thing actually, like embedding a JWT within a JWT.

Here is what I'd like to do in summary:

[image]